# Drag and Drop in subelement works strange

Tags: jquery, html

I've build a Drag and Drop system like this:
Here is a List that can be Drop into a editable Div:
The list code is like this:

```
<li class='file'>test<li>
$("li.file").bind("dragstart",function(e){
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllow='move';
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text',$(this).text());
});`
```

Then i got a Div to get the drag item:

```
<div id='editor'><div>
$("#editor").bind('dragover',function(e){
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect="move";
if(e.preventDefault){
e.preventDefault();
});
$("#editor").bind('drop',function(e){
    if (e.target==$('#editor')[0]){
#add a sub <div class="editorcontent"> under the <div id='editor'>
}
```

Those code works fine.Now I want to add a new drag and drop event on the
 'div.editorcontent to allow two different editorcontent div to switch their position:

```
$("div.editorcontent").bind("dragstart",function(e){
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllow='move';
});
$("div.editorcontent").bind("dragover",function(e){
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect="move";
if(e.preventDefault){
e.preventDefault();
}

});
$("div.editorcontent").bind("drop",function(e){
    alert(e.target);
});
```

But those code doesn't work. I've set breakpoints at chrome and seems that only #editor's drag and drop event are in use. Whenever i drag the div.editorcontent no event happens.When I drop the div.editorcontent element on the other div.editorcontent. The chrome go in to  the #editor's drop event.So how can i fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when $.ready the new add div are not exists,so the new handler to those divs are not bound on those divs.